# easiest way for inline python with apache (mod_python)?

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

if have an existing webpage (simple HTML) where i want to include some python.
The website isn´t written by me, so i can not write the whole page in python. The web-server is an Apache.

At the moment i solved it with an inlineframe  from the same directory and server which is a bit dirty (but it does what i want) :-/

```
<Directory /var/www/folder>
  AddHandler mod_python .py
  PythonHandler scriptname
  PythonDebug Off
</Directory>
```

some php-like inline python would help me.

I´am testing some psp (Python Server Pages) but is that the easiest way to do that?

I don´t want to use JavaScript to load the "frame" with python-code

Comment: Hi Matze, I tried something like that once, using mod-rewrite or something like that but all the work was useless, so I used and I strongly recommend django-compressor(https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor).